# What does "Take a collective look" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Surely the fortieth anniversary is a good time to take a collective look at this problem.

What does ***Take a collective look*** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a context such as:

> Encouraging the discipline to take a collective look at itself
>
> [google books: The Handbook of Sociocultural Anthropology](https://books.google.com/books?id=8CweAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=Take+a+%22collective+look%22&source=bl&ots=D3DoyT5zJS&sig=3-bQWlrWNkUTTr8IChZ8oeK3PyY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUnr2h1-TKAhWB4CYKHbrcBRIQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=Take%20a%20%22collective%20look%22&f=false)

The collective is those who practice the discipline.  It's encouraging all of them to examine the way they practice their discipline.

In your example:

> Surely the fortieth anniversary is a good time to take a collective look at this problem.

It's not clear what the problem is or who is having their fortieth anniversary.  But whoever they are, they are being encouraged to look at the problem together.

> **col·lec·tive**
>
> kəˈlektiv/Submit
>
> adjective
>
> 1. done by people acting as a group.
>
> "a collective protest"
>
> noun
>
> 1. a cooperative enterprise.
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=collective&oq=collective&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=collective+meaning)